# Where are the default system icons for folders and files stored? 

Tags: snow-leopard, folders, icon

Where are the default/system icons for folders and files stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default icons are stored in various locations inside `/System/Library` - is there a specific icon you're looking for?

Finder.app (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources`) has the Smart Folder icons and the Burnable folder icons for example.

Most of the more known icons (eg. pictures for the default folders among many others) can be found at `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`

Comment: +1 for path,but if I want change some of them can replace my Icon with current icon (just name it the same)?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: You could - it's easier to use a program like [CandyBar](http://panic.com/candybar) to handle all that for you.

Comment: Also, another way is to copy the image you want into the clipboard, select the folder icon you want to change, Get Info, select the icon in the top left, and paste. This is best if you have just a few folders you'd like to change; otherwise, I'd also recommend something like CandyBar or ThemePark.